# How to skip license dialog of a WIX installer if a condition is raised

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix3.7

At the moment everytime i make an update of my product the license dialog is shown. Since the user has accepted the license at the first installation and the EULA has not changed in the meantime it is unnecessary to show the dialog again.

My idea is to set a registry key if the EULA was accepted and at an update i will proceed a registry search and if the key is found i want to skip the license dialog.

How can i archieve this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sample UI examples that are like this:

where Not Installed is a condition on the dialog. So you need to:

1. In the original install write a registryitem that says the EULA has been read.
2. In the new install, do a registrysearch for that item to set a property, then put that property in the License dialog with a condition something like Not LICENSEHASBEENREAD

You may need to make your own copy of the Wix UI to add that condition.

Comment: It deleted my Xml answer, hopefully you found it somewhere.